# How to find out the name of the packages involved in the proprietary driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers, hardware, proprietary

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my HP Mini 110-3110BR for test purposes.

A notification about a proprietary driver popped up. It's for the Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01). After I activated it, it worked perfectly.

But I also want to reinstall Debian on this machine. I had it before, and wireless worked perfectly, but I remember I had a very hard time to make it work.

So, I want to know how to extract more information from the proprietary driver on Ubuntu, to make it work on Debian. I think that the name of the packages involved would be enough.

I want to make it work from the installation. I don't want to install it with ethernet, like I did before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To see a list of third-party drivers.

```
jockey-text -l
```

Comment: `kmod:wl - Broadcom STA wireless driver`


Not the information I was expecting, but thanks anyway. I'll look around a little more and do some tests.

Comment: The package that you need is broadcom-sta-dkms. `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms`

Comment: That's weird, this package doesn't appear in the repos, even with `contrib non-free` added to `sources.list`. Yet, wireless is working on Ubuntu. I already got some package names and I'm working on testing them.

Comment: Looks likes it's a 12.10 package only. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/broadcom-sta-dkms.